# Can I play on Lichess with my own "client"?

Tags: online-chess

I love [Lichess](https://en.lichess.org/). It's web based client, but I want to use a program like Scid, scid vs Pc, or babaschess, or any of this clients programs used in FICS: [see bottom links this page](http://fics.freechess.org/interfaces.html). Those programs offer possibilities Lichess doesn't such as annotate games move per move, choose engines to run in your own PC (to the contrary on the cloud like lichess, wich could be slower). Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lichess does not support the FICS-interface, therefore clients used for FICS do not support it. At the moment you can only play it via a web-client.

<s>Maybe in the future the Lichess-API allows sending and receiving moves, etc.</s> Apparently it is already possible as the API already allows it via HTTP, see [Link](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/tree/master/doc/mobile).

EDIT:
As stated in this [issue tracker thread](https://github.com/pychess/pychess/issues/1332) *pychess* is interested in integrating Lichess support. An official desktop client will most likely not come in the near future as the web GUI is fantastic already and developers can use the time to further improve the current codebase.

Comment: Can you give me sources?

Comment: Seems the closer I will get to a solution, so I accept it!